# Make Jira Api request more efficient

Tags: api, process, jira

I extract my data from Jira into my database using the JiraAPi, more specifically I take the issues and the worklogs. The problem is that it takes a lot of time to get and process all the data, at every request.

I would like to find a way to extract form Jira just the new data(let's say the new and updated issues and worklogs from the last hour, or something like that). This way, the process will be much shorter, as the actually changed data is just like 5% of the total amount.

I'm kind of new to programming and so far I could not find related documentation..
Any idea would be appreciated. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
/rest/api/latest/search?jql=updated>"2023-03-29 07:00"
```

You can refer to JQL reference, especially the date and time functions:

https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-functions/